# html simple way to find and locate an element or text

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so i have a problem i have simple html website filled with text and i want to make button which has an onclick function that makes my window(the position at the moment of the page) locate an element with id="element" and change the window position.like the ctr+F function but withouth highlighting the element

```
<head>
<script>
    function h1Location(){

                   enter code here
    }       

</script>
</head>
<body>
   <header >
        <div  style="position:fixed;">
        <input type="button" onclick="h1Location()" />
        </div>
   </header>

   <nav>
       <h1 id="firstHeader"   >TEXT</h1>

   </nav>
</body>
```

So in this case i simply want to make the button locate and change PageView to 'TEXT'(h1 with id="firstHeader" so instead of scrolling up or down it immediately do it for you.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? In-page anchor links have have done this since the dawn of HTML.

Comment: To add to Diodeus' comment in order to go to `<h1 id="firstHeader">` add an anchor tag with href to #firstHeader e.g. `<a href="#firstHeader">First Header</a>`

Answer (score 0):

In page anchor links:

```
    Click <a href="#placeToScroll">here</a> to see some lower down part the author thinks is important. 

<!--REST OF PAGE-->

    <a name="placeToScroll">Here's that lower down part!</a>
```